# Find number of reads/writes on a collection

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know the number of reads and number of writes per day that happen on a collection in mongoldb. Is there a way to find this. 
   We have statistics on the overall read and write happening on a cluster. But can we find the values on a collection level. How do we get such data.

Answer (score 2):

You could derive that information from the "cursor" subdocument that you get from the built-in [collStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/) command like so:

```
db.runCommand( { collStats: "yourcollection" } )
```

This command does not split the information by day but since the output of it is nicely structured JSON, you should be able to run this command once a day, capture the output and perform some custom analysis on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the output from this command does not have the read/write load.

Comment: You need to replace the "yourcollection" with the name of your collection. Then, inside the "cursor" sub-document, you get the "insert calls" counter, the "update calls", the "remove calls" and the "search calls" - what else do you need? But I think you need to be using the WiredTiger Storage Engine for that to work properly.

Comment: @dnickless what do the "insert calls"/"update calls" etc mean?